# Drag and Drop Storagefile from one listview to another

Tags: c#, listview, drag-and-drop, uwp, storagefile

I have 2 list views and I'm trying to drag an item from one to the other. 
The typeof item is a storagefile.

```
private async void ListA_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        List<IStorageItem> files = new List<IStorageItem>();
        StorageFile file = e.Items;
        files.Add(file);

        e.Data.SetStorageItems(files);
    }
    private void ListC_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;

    }
    private async void ListC_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        //if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
        //{

        //    var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
        //    if (items.Count > 0)
        //    {
        //        var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
        //        ListC.Items.Add(storageFile);
        //    }
        // }

    }
```

I've tried everything I can think of to drop the storage file into the other listview and show the display name... All I've been able to display are types and stuff.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it after hours or trying.

```
        private async void ListA_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
    {
        //f.MessageBox(e.Items.First().GetType().ToString());
        try
        {
            List<IStorageItem> files = new List<IStorageItem>();
            StorageFile file = e.Items.First() as StorageFile;
            files.Add(file);
            e.Data.SetStorageItems(files);
            //e.Data.SetData(StandardDataFormats.Text, e.Items.);


        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            f.MessageBox(ex.Message);
        }

    }
    private async void ListC_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
        //IReadOnlyList<IStorageItem> files = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();


    }
    private async void ListC_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
            {


                var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    var storageFile = items[0] as StorageFile;
                    ListC.Items.Add(storageFile.Name);
                }
            }
        }catch
        {
            f.MessageBox("nope");
        }
```